# How I can use TSP function in pgRouting 2.0?

Tags: pgrouting, routing

I've spent years working with pgRouting and so far he had solved the problems I had needed. With the change to version 2.0, things improved, everything was much more organized and new algorithms that, which gives solution to dissimilar problems were incorporated. My question is related to the new TSP algorithm implementation, and not how to use it. I wish someone would put me an example of how on a network of 200,000 or more lines calculate a route with TSP of 5 0 6 waypoints.

Answer (score 1):

Check the source code in the repository:

https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/blob/master/src/tsp/src/tsplib.c

It says:

```
* Simulated annealing and a non symetric
* Euclidian Traveling Salesman Problem.
* Solution based on local search heuristics for
* non-crossing paths and nearest neighbors
```

So it seems there is a simulated annealing algorithm in place:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing

Comment: Route XL, I know this, but i just need a simple example (5 - 6 wayspoints)  to  show me how i can use TSP in pgRouting 2.0 in a real database. The documentation in pgRouting web site is poor and use a little database. I don't know how apply this function in my database.

Comment: @pedro3102 I am sorry. I guess I was triggered by this part of your question: "My question is related to the new TSP algorithm implementation, and not how to use it".